# Android Screen goes blank on orientation change; onConfigurationChanged is called

Tags: android, android-activity

When my activity's (tab activity with two tabs) orientation is changed, the content of the tabs, which is another activity with a listview of items(with checkboxes), GOES BLANK. I have used `android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"` in the manifest file, so that I dont want the checkboxes to be cleared(or recreated) on orientation change.

Could anyone please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to save the state of View's within activities in Android you need to implement the `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` and `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` methods. See the [Android Developer Guide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ConfigurationChanges) for more on these methods.

`onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` is called when the activity is destroyed on configuration change (change in orientation). You can add data to the bundle in this method and then retrieve it when the activity is restarted using `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)`.

For example:

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    // Read values from the "savedInstanceState" bundle and put them back into the corresponding textviews
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    // Save the values you need from your textviews into the outState object
}
```

For more details on how to save data into bundles see the [Android Developer Guide](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html). This also explains the difference between restoring state using `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` and `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)`.